# Needing to do a simple Find/Replace in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm needing to do a very important database string correction on 192 rows and am wondering if this is correct syntax:

```
UPDATE `DATABASE_NAME`.`TABLE_NAME` SET `FIELD_NAME` = REPLACE(`FIELD_NAME`,`REPLACE_THIS_STRING`,`WITH_THIS_STRING`);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find out is to write it as a `SELECT` statement first to "preview" the results.

```
SELECT field_name As before
     , Replace(field_name, 'replace this string', 'with this string') As after
FROM   table_name
```

Optional `WHERE` clause (to only affect the rows that contain our replacement string):

```
...
WHERE  field_name LIKE '%replace this string%'
```

Comment: This is very good approach to ensure that you only update the rows you want to!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i would write it like this

```
UPDATE `DATABASE_NAME`.`TABLE_NAME` SET `FIELD_NAME` = 
REPLACE(`FIELD_NAME`,`REPLACE_THIS_VALUE`,`WITH_THIS_VALUE`);
```

Does the table only contain these 192 rows? Otherwise you must add a `WHERE` to the syntax. Or it will update all FIELD_NAME rows.

As @gvee suggest, try to select the rows first and see how the result looks like to ensure the update scope is correct